# Communication between STM32 and C# via ESP8266

Tags: c#, stm32, esp8266

I'm now trying to connect STM32F429 to C# desktop application with ESP8266(in STA mode). I want ESP8266 to be a client and C# to be a Server. However ESP8266 remains failing to find my PC in the same LAN.

- Now I have succeeded to use AT command to connect ESP8266 to my Router AP. And I used XAMPP to open a gate on my PC whose address is 192.168.1.11:80, then use the following command (AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.1.11\",80")  to successfully connect ESP8266 to it(It returned OK to my STM32F429).
  Then I wanna replace XAMPP with my C# code to open a TCP server. But I couldn't make it!
- As for the C# Code, I have successfully build a connection between two C# programs (The IP Address is 192.168.1.11:80 which is the same as the one mentioned above).But when I tried to use ESP8266 to connect to the same IP and Port, it failed.

I suspected that there might be some wrong conceptions I have got about opening a TCP Listener on certain port in my LAN... I don't know...

The following is my C# code. (The code of STM32 is just a basic Usart code which I won't present here.)

```cs
// Code for Server
namespace Tcp_Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private TcpListener myListener;
        private TcpClient newClient;
        public BinaryReader br;
        public BinaryWriter bw;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread myThread = new Thread(ServerA);
            myThread.Start();

        }

        private void ServerA()
        {
            IPAddress SvrIP = new IPAddress(Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0].Address); // Get the virtual IP of my PC.

            this.Invoke(new AddToTextbox_dg(AddToTextbox), new object[] { tb_ServerStatus, ip.ToString() });
            myListener = new TcpListener(ip, 80); //construct a Tcp Listener.
            myListener.Start(); //Tcp Listener start
            newClient = myListener.AcceptTcpClient();// Searching for a client...

            this.Invoke(new AddToTextbox_dg(AddToTextbox), new object[] { tb_ServerStatus, "Connect Successfully" });

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    NetworkStream clientStream = newClient.GetStream();
                    br = new BinaryReader(clientStream);
                    string receive = null;
                    receive = br.ReadString();//读取
                    this.Invoke(new AddToTextbox_dg(AddToTextbox), new object[] { tb_ServerStatus, receive });
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Receving failed...");
                }
            }
        }
```

```
// Code for client
namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private TcpClient client;
        public BinaryReader br;
        public BinaryWriter bw;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread myThread = new Thread(ClientA);
            myThread.Start();
        }

        private void ClientA()
        {
            IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0].Address); // Get the virtual IP of my PC.
            client = new TcpClient(ip.ToString(), 80);
            this.Invoke(new AddToTextbox_dg(AddToTextbox), new object[] { tb_ServerStatus, "Connect to Server Successfully!" });
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
                    br = new BinaryReader(clientStream);
                    string receive = null;
                    receive = br.ReadString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Receving failed...");
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddToTextbox(TextBox txt, String s)

        {

            txt.Text += s;

        }
        private delegate void AddToTextbox_dg(TextBox txt, String s);

        private void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
            bw = new BinaryWriter(clientStream);
            bw.Write(message.Text);

        }
    }
}
```

Could somebody please help me with this problem ?

- I wonder why I cannot connect ESP8266 to the TcpListener I built on my PC with C#.
- What did my PC do when receiving the command: 
  myListener = new TcpListener(ip, 80);
- This project I'm doing is about to transmit the image data I got with Stm32F429 and OV7725  to my PC through ESP8266. I know Usart will be too slow to do that, but now I'm just trying to build the connection. Is there any suggestion you guys could give me about this?

Comment: possibly a firewall issue?

Comment: So my concept about the port is right ?
But I still wonder why I can casually choose a IP to open a TcpListener. It's quite weird.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure no other application on your pc is listening to port 80. if so, you have to change it.

Second, try setting the ip of the TCPListener to local host "127.0.0.1". you will be able to reach this server by connecting to the ip of your PC.

Comment: Could u please check the answer below. I did send some pictures showing what I did. I wanna know if I misunderstood anything or did anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the used IP in command window as below:

[Command Window for checking IP usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpPoC.png)

And I remain the IP address which ESP8266 will try to access to be 192.168.1.11:1900 which is the virtual IP of my PC in the LAN as below:

[Address ESP8266 try to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HXsK.png)

And change the IP C#  will try to create a TCPListener on:

[C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5JM0.png)

Is this what you mean? Thank you.